# What is needed to make the "Hello World" example available to all devices on the Android market?

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, galaxy, android-market-filtering

I have problems to get my application available for some devices. So I decided to keep it simple and go back to the "Hello World" example project, and try to make that available for those devices. Unfortunately, no matter what I try, the market keeps filtering it for the good old Samsung Galaxy i7500 and the T-Mobile G1 (HTC).

1. Copy Protection is Off, the application is "Free" and available for all countries but Unpublished (I'm not trying to download it ... yet).
2. The Manifest file has:

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
   ```
3. The manifest really has no other filters (permissions, uses-.. or supports-...)
4. I'm using eclipse, Indigo on Ubuntu Linux (11.04)
5. SDK version r14
6. Problem existed also on Eclipse Helios, Android SDK version r10
7. The Market application info states:

   ```
   This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
       Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
       Required device features
           android.hardware.touchscreen
   This application is available to over 694 devices.
   ```
8. Unsupported devices (some examples) are:

   ```
   HTC
    G1 (trout)
    Touch Viva (opal)
   Samsung
    Behold II (sgh-t939)
    Galaxy (gt-i7500)
    Moment (sph-m900)
    Spica (spica)
   ```

   At least the G1 and the i7500 have a touchscreen, so that can not be the problem.
9. The Hello World project is made in Eclipse, with File->New->Android Project , and then just add the line mentioned in 2) in the manifest file. Sign, upload to market, save, and check the Device Availability Dialog.

It worked fine until somewhere in september, after I used the Android SDK Manager in Eclipse to update to the latest release. Am I the only one with this problem? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug going on. The same thing actually happened to me. I ended up renaming my package and uploading it to the market and then it worked. This may be a solution you can try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the proposed solution and it doesn't help. After renaming the package you have to upload it as a new application. So this is similar to creating a new one, which is what I basically already did when I made the Hello World app to narrow down the possible causes of the defect compared to my real app. It's almost as if google's market filter settings rule out the listed phones for all possible filter combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those devices can't even have android market so don't worry

reference: https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1141080

android version must be over 1.5 and those cellphones are:
G1         android v1.1
gt-i7500   android v1.5
Touch Viva Windows Mobile
Behold II  android v1.5
(sph-m900) android v1.5
...

"Device is running Android 1.5

At this time, the Android Market website is only compatible with devices running Android 1.6 or higher. If your device is running Android 1.5, we recommend contacting your carrier or device manufacturer to see if an update to a higher version of Android is available."

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy was recently repaired because of an issue with the USB port. When I got it back, it had an official 1.6 image installed from Samsung. When I posted my original question, it was already repaired (so it was running with Android v1.6). But I couldn't download my app. I tried again today and now it works, even though the device availability tool still sais it is not supported for this phone.